# UCanAccess "object not found" error for query that references its own column alias

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

Since JDBC:ODBC bridge in not longer supported by JAVA 8 I try to replace it with Ucanaccess V3.0, but II am facing some issue, see following.

This is the code I use in order to connect to my database :

```
String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/ADEL/ADEL Local/ADEL_DATA.accdb";
        try
        {
            //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

        }
        catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            ErrorFile.writeError(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber(), e);
        }
```

To run query I the same code I previously using with JDBC:ODBC

```
Connection c = ConnectDB.doConnect();

String selectString = "SELECT DISTINCT [Maintenance input Check Due List].[Interval (Mos)], [Maintenance input Check Due List].InputAircraftHours, [Maintenance input Check Due List].InputAircraftLandings,  [Maintenance input Check Due List].Check, [Maintenance input Check Due List].Title, [Maintenance input Check Due List].InputNumber, [Maintenance input Check Due List].AircraftCurrentTSN, [Maintenance input Check Due List].AircraftCurrentCSN, [Maintenance input Check Due List].Aircraft, [Maintenance input Check Due List].InputDateOUT, [Maintenance input Check Due List].[Interval (Hrs)], [Maintenance input Check Due List].[Interval(Ldgs)], [Maintenance input Check Due List].[NextDueCheckMonth], [Maintenance input Check Due List].NextDueCheckHours, [Maintenance input Check Due List].NextDueCheckLdgs, [Maintenance input Check Due List].RemainCheckMonth, [Maintenance input Check Due List].RemainCheckHours,[Maintenance input Check Due List].RemainCheckLdgs,[Maintenance input Check Due List].InputRepairStation,[Maintenance input Check Due List].InputDescription "
            + "FROM [Maintenance input table] RIGHT JOIN ([Maintenance Schedule Check] RIGHT JOIN   [...]

try
    {
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet data = stmt.executeQuery(selectString);
        System.out.print("(AircraftDueList-ln539) " + "requete passed\n");
        while (data.next())
        {[...]}
}
catch (SQLException e)
    {
        ErrorFile.writeError(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber(), e);
        System.err.println("SQLException: "
                + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this query throw an exception :

```
 SQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.0 user lacks privilege or object not found: NEXTDUECHECKMONTH
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.0 user lacks privilege or object not found: NEXTDUECHECKMONTH
at     net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:211)
at main.AircraftDueList.inspPack(AircraftDueList.java:626)
at main.AircraftDueList.createPDF(AircraftDueList.java:88)
at main.AircraftList.<init>(AircraftList.java:166)
at Launch.main(Launch.java:13)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: NEXTDUECHECKMONTH
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:208)
... 4 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: NEXTDUECHECKMONTH
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.RangeVariable.resolveRangeTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveRangeVariables(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveReferences(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadJoinedTableAsSubqueryOrNull(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

This query call tables and stored query in access, "NEXTDUECHECKMONTH" is an alias field from a stored query in access named "[Maintenance input Check Due List]".

In the stored query [Maintenance input Check Due List] the field NEXTDUECHECKMONTH is construct like this :

```
IIf([Interval (Mos)] Is Null,Null,DateAdd("m",[Interval (Mos)],[InputDateOUT])) AS NextDueCheckMonth
```

Someone have successfully facing this kind of issue ?

PS : All my query's run successfully in ACCESS

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the Java code for an [mcve] that produces the error. I was unable to recreate your issue using a simple SELECT statement on the saved query.

Comment: I try to improve my post, I think past the query here is not very helpful because it's a big and confusing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to the other answer, the problem was that the query had a WHERE clause trying to reference a column alias that was defined in the same query. That doesn't work in UCanAccess, e.g.,

```java
sql = 
        "SELECT Date1 AS DateAlias " +
        "FROM DateTest " +
        "WHERE DateAlias IS NOT NULL";
```

throws

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.0 user lacks privilege or object not found: DATEALIAS

but it also does not work in Access itself since Access does not recognize the alias as a column name and therefore prompts us for a parameter value:

[image: ParameterPrompt.png]

One workaround for this issue would be to encapsulate the original query as a subquery so the outer query can use the alias:

```java
sql = 
        "SELECT DateAlias " +
        "FROM (SELECT Date1 AS DateAlias FROM DateTest) " +
        "WHERE DateAlias IS NOT NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem : I try to create alias in my query and using them in this query; Ucanaccess don't like it.

Comment: Are you talking about a table alias in the FROM clause of your query, e.g., `... FROM ... RIGHT JOIN [Maintenance input Check Due List] AS micdl ...`? If so, then you need to use the table alias (and not the table/query name) in the column list (SELECT ...) as well.

Comment: I speak about a row alias : in this query I have `IIf([Interval (Mos)] Is Null,Null,DateAdd("m",[Interval (Mos)],[InputDateOUT])) AS NextDueCheckMonth` but some lines after there is condition like `WHERE NextDueCheckMonth = ...` to solve this issue i replace it by `WHERE IIf([Interval (Mos)] Is Null,Null,DateAdd("m",[Interval (Mos)],[InputDateOUT])) = ...`